# Replace with withColumn in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Can you help me understand the following error message and the reason behind it:

Create a dummy dataset:

```
df_=spark.createDataFrame([(1, np.nan,'x'), (None, 2.0,'y'),(3,4.0,None)], ("a", "b","c"))
df_.show()
+----+---+----+
|   a|  b|   c|
+----+---+----+
|   1|NaN|   x|
|null|2.0|   y|
|   3|4.0|null|
+----+---+----+
```

Now, I attempt to replace the NaN in the column 'b' the following way:

```
df_.withColumn("b", df_.select("b").replace({float("nan"):5}).b)
```

The `df_.select("b").replace({float("nan"):5}).b` runs just fine and gives a proper column with the expected value. Yet the code above is not working and I am not able to understand the error

The error that I am getting is:

```
AnalysisException                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[170], line 1
----> 1 df_.withColumn("b", df_.select("b").replace({float("nan"):5}).b)

File /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py:2455, in DataFrame.withColumn(self, colName, col)
   2425 """
   2426 Returns a new :class:`DataFrame` by adding a column or replacing the
   2427 existing column that has the same name.
   (...)
   2452 
   2453 """
   2454 assert isinstance(col, Column), "col should be Column"
-> 2455 return DataFrame(self._jdf.withColumn(colName, col._jc), self.sql_ctx)

File /opt/conda/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1304, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1298 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1299     self.command_header +\
   1300     args_command +\
   1301     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1303 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304 return_value = get_return_value(
   1305     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1307 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1308     temp_arg._detach()

File /usr/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py:117, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    113 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    114 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    115     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    116     # JVM exception message.
--> 117     raise converted from None
    118 else:
    119     raise

AnalysisException: Resolved attribute(s) b#1083 missing from a#930L,b#931,c#932 in operator !Project [a#930L, b#1083 AS b#1085, c#932]. Attribute(s) with the same name appear in the operation: b. Please check if the right attribute(s) are used.;
!Project [a#930L, b#1083 AS b#1085, c#932]
+- LogicalRDD [a#930L, b#931, c#932], false
```

I can achieve the required objective by using the subset argument in the replace API. i.e. `df_.replace({float("nan"):5},subset = ['b'])` However, I am trying to understand better the error that I am seeing and the cause behind it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, my quandary is not related to filling in the missing values. I can achieve that. Through this example, I am trying to understand some nuance in the spark that is not letting me use the approach I have mentioned hoping I will learn something about withColumn. In withColumn I have supplied a transformation of the already existing column in the dataframe. I do not understand what is going wrong and why am I seeing the error that I have mentioned above

Comment: For `withColumn` method, you can write: `df_.withColumn("b", F.when(F.isnan("b"), 5).otherwise(F.col("b")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation of [`df.withColumn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html):

> Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing
> column that has the same name.
>
> The column expression must be an expression over this DataFrame;
> attempting to add a column from some other DataFrame will raise an
> error.

So when you do
`df_.select("b").replace({float("nan"):5}).b` this creates a different dataframe with a different attribute id of column `b` (since `df_.select` returns a new dataframe). This attribute id doesnot exist in the original dataframe.

You should instead use replace with subset which refers to the same pointer from the same dataframe

```
new_df = df_.replace({float("nan"):5},subset='b')
new_df.explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [a#2131L, CASE WHEN (b#2132 = NaN) THEN 5.0 ELSE b#2132 END AS b#2351, c#2133]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[a#2131L,b#2132,c#2133]
```

Note how the attribute pointer changes below:

```
df1 = df_
df1.replace({float("nan"):5},subset='b').explain()

== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [a#2131L, CASE WHEN (b#2132 = NaN) THEN 5.0 ELSE b#2132 END AS b#2378, c#2133]
+- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[a#2131L,b#2132,c#2133]
```